# Parts of the object vanish in edit mode

Tags: modeling

I have built a bookcase and added a cornice in Edit mode before toggling to Object mode. Now, when I toggle back to Edit mode, everything disappears apart from the added cornice.  I tried copying the object but the copy has the same behavior.  Is this a bug, a feature or a silly mistake?

Comment: please provide your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you

Comment: Try pressing Alt+H while in Edit mode. And / or show some screenshots of the mesh in Object and Edit mode.

Comment: Thank you so much both - especially Mr Zak.  The Alt + H worked in Edit mode (why didn't I think of that? - presumably I must have inadvertently hidden part of the object in edit mode)